# Footnote hyperlink going to the first page, not to the footnote

Tags: amsmath, footnotes, hyperlink

I am using Overleaf. If I click the blue-colored hyperlink for the footnote on the pdf file, it goes to the front page, not to the footnote as I intended. How should I fix this? I am using the following structure:

```
\documentclass[11pt,english]{extarticle}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=Matlab}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[title,titletoc,toc]{appendix}
\usepackage[nohead]{geometry}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[center,bf]{caption}
\usepackage{morefloats}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\parindent}{24pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{0in}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{natbib}
\setlength{\bibsep}{0pt plus 0.3ex}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{adjustbox}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% This package makes you cross-reference across different tex files.
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
filecolor=black
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\addFileDependency}[1]{
  \typeout{(#1)}
  \@addtofilelist{#1}
  \IfFileExists{#1}{}{\typeout{No file #1.}}
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\myexternaldocument}[1]{
    \externaldocument{#1}
    \addFileDependency{#1.tex}
    \addFileDependency{#1.aux}
}
%%% END HELPER CODE

\myexternaldocument{online_appendix}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\usepackage{verbatim} 
\usepackage{setspace}
\linespread{1.3}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{ragged2e}


%%%%%%%%%%% Suppress Warning
\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{latex}{Text page}
\WarningFilter*{natbib}{Citation}
\WarningFilter*{natbib}{There}
 

\usepackage{changepage}
\newlength{\wideitemsep}
\setlength{\wideitemsep}{\itemsep}
\addtolength{\wideitemsep}{5pt}
\let\olditem\item
\renewcommand{\item}{\setlength{\itemsep}{7pt}\olditem}


\newcommand{\sym}[1]{{#1}}

\long\def\/*#1*/{}


%%%%%%
% Make Title appear in the top of the page
\usepackage{titling}
%\setlength{\droptitle}{-4em}
\setlength{\droptitle}{-2em}
%%%%%%



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%% Directly brought from Lyx %%%%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
%\geometry{verbose,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=3cm,lmargin=3cm,rmargin=3cm}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2.7cm,bmargin=2.7cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm}
%\geometry{verbose,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=3cm,lmargin=2.3cm,rmargin=2.3cm}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{setspace}
%\doublespacing


\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{\protect\theoremname}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{\protect\propositionname}
\ifx\proof\undefined
\newenvironment{proof}[1][\protect\proofname]{\par
    \normalfont\topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
    \trivlist
    \itemindent\parindent
    \item[\hskip\labelsep\scshape #1]\ignorespaces
}{%
    \endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\providecommand{\proofname}{Proof}
\fi
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{\protect\corollaryname}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\providecommand{\corollaryname}{Corollary}
\providecommand{\propositionname}{Proposition}
\providecommand{\theoremname}{Theorem}

\begin{document}




\title{\textbf{\large{}!!title}\thanks{!!acknowledgement}}



\date{{\normalsize{}!!date \endgraf 
\vspace{0.5mm}
}}
\maketitle
%% Do not number title page
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\let\cleardoublepage\relax
\thispagestyle{empty}%<=======
\endgroup   

\newpage{}
\setcounter{page}{1}


\section{Introduction}
\label{section:introduction} 

Words\footnote{hi}


\newpage{}

\begin{singlespacing} %\nocite{*}
 \bibliographystyle{aer}
\bibliography{Reference}
 \end{singlespacing}


\end{document}
```

Comment: The first step is usually to start removing packages and superfluous code.  If the problem goes away, then you know the caused it.

Comment: Pretty sure the problem is that you're loading hyperref too early. Hyperref should usually be loaded after other packages. Try moving the lines loading xr-hyper, hyperref and hypersetup packages until almost right before `\begin{document}`. You may need to move the `\myexternaldocument` stuff till after that as well.

Comment: Unrelated but you're also loading the geometry, amssymb and setspace packages twice. You should take one out.

Comment: Does LaTeX really have such a huge number of packages?

Comment: The setspace package changes footnotes and should therefore be loaded before hyperref. And you are resetting the page number to 1. That will confuse links too. Give the title page a different numbering style. The \clearpage code is nonsense and I have some doubts that your document is really latin9 encoded.

Comment: @wipet CTAN currently hosts 6289 packages. Of course they are not all for LaTeX but most are. For me that points to a healthy ecosystem with lots of contributors, and a range of functionality beyond imagination :)

Comment: @Marijn CTAN hosts my packages too but they surely are not LaTeX packages. And healthy ecosystem? There are users they insert huge `\usepackage` without understanding what the packages are doing and then the users put a desperate question "somethig is wrong" (like here). This doesn't confirm the opinion of "healthy" ecosystem :)

Comment: @frabjous It worked after putting hyperref after other packages. This same code has another problem though. I asked this question here. I will appreciate it if you could tell me how to fix this. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/660242/citation-links-on-pdf-are-being-created-on-both-author-list-and-year