# Citation links on pdf are being created on both author list and year

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, citing, natbib, hyperlink

The following is what I am doing now.

```
\documentclass[11pt,english]{extarticle}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=Matlab}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[title,titletoc,toc]{appendix}
\usepackage[nohead]{geometry}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[center,bf]{caption}
\usepackage{morefloats}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\parindent}{24pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{0in}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{natbib}
\setlength{\bibsep}{0pt plus 0.3ex}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\usepackage{verbatim} 
\usepackage{setspace}
\linespread{1.3}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{ragged2e}


%%%%%%%%%%% Suppress Warning
\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{latex}{Text page}
\WarningFilter*{natbib}{Citation}
\WarningFilter*{natbib}{There}
 

\usepackage{changepage}
\newlength{\wideitemsep}
\setlength{\wideitemsep}{\itemsep}
\addtolength{\wideitemsep}{5pt}
\let\olditem\item
\renewcommand{\item}{\setlength{\itemsep}{7pt}\olditem}


\newcommand{\sym}[1]{{#1}}

\long\def\/*#1*/{}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Make Title appear in the top of the page
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{titling}
%\setlength{\droptitle}{-4em}
\setlength{\droptitle}{-2em}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%% Directly brought from Lyx %%%%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2.7cm,bmargin=2.7cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm}
\usepackage{amsthm}



\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{\protect\theoremname}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{\protect\propositionname}
\ifx\proof\undefined
\newenvironment{proof}[1][\protect\proofname]{\par
    \normalfont\topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
    \trivlist
    \itemindent\parindent
    \item[\hskip\labelsep\scshape #1]\ignorespaces
}{%
    \endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\providecommand{\proofname}{Proof}
\fi
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{\protect\corollaryname}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\providecommand{\corollaryname}{Corollary}
\providecommand{\propositionname}{Proposition}
\providecommand{\theoremname}{Theorem}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% This package makes you cross-reference across different tex files.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
filecolor=black
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\addFileDependency}[1]{
  \typeout{(#1)}
  \@addtofilelist{#1}
  \IfFileExists{#1}{}{\typeout{No file #1.}}
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\myexternaldocument}[1]{
    \externaldocument{#1}
    \addFileDependency{#1.tex}
    \addFileDependency{#1.aux}
}
%%% END HELPER CODE

\myexternaldocument{online_appendix}



\begin{document}


\newpage{}
\setcounter{page}{1}


\section{Introduction}
\label{section:introduction} 

Words\footnote{hi}

Citation examples: 

\cite{Coase1992AER}




\newpage{}

\begin{singlespacing} %\nocite{*}
 \bibliographystyle{aer}
\bibliography{Reference}
 \end{singlespacing}


\end{document}
```

The reference I am using is

```
@article{Coase1992AER,
  title={The Institutional Structure of Production},
  author={Ronald H. Coase},
  journal={American Economic Review},
  volume={82},
  number={4},
  pages={713---719},
  year={1992}
}
```

Then, what happens is I get two separate links.

I correctly get this

[image]

But if I hover my mouse over the author name, this link applies only to the author name

[image]

IF I hover my mouse over the year, this link applies only to the year part.

[image]

But the standard way to make hyperlink is to create one unified link across the author names and the year, correct? Then I want to follow the standard practice. How can I do that?

---

*Addendum*: The same material as before, but now in the form of a minimum working example or [MWE](https://(https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)):

```
\documentclass[11pt,english]{extarticle}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{Reference.bib}
@article{Coase1992AER,
  title  ={The Institutional Structure of Production},
  author ={Ronald H. Coase},
  journal={American Economic Review},
  volume ={82},
  number ={4},
  pages  ={713-719},
  year   ={1992}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{aer}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue, linkcolor=blue, 
            citecolor=blue, filecolor=black]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\cite{Coase1992AER}
\bibliography{Reference}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if we can say there is a standard way that would imply that the entire citation has to be linked in one go. I don't know the exact implementation and rationale in `natbib`, but in `biblatex` the author is usually not linked at all and linking it and the year in one go would make things *significantly* more fiddly in the implementation. ...

Comment: ... I guess it is similar for `natbib`. If you cite a second work by the same author from a different year, say, `\cite{Coase1992AER,Coase1993}` gives you "Coase (1992, 1993)". It's not clear which source the name should link to here (granted, this may not be a strong argument in your book, as you could just pick one), but here linking in one go is not really possible as you have two works and you have to split the link somewhere to take your readers to both works. Frankly, I wouldn't bother.

Comment: For future questions you may want to consider reducing the code you post a bit to focus on the relevant parts only. The preamble contains a bunch of packages that have no impact on bibliography, citations and links. And it's a nice gesture to show that you value the time of those who read your question to try and present them with only the necessary code.

Comment: Off-topic: With `pages={713---719}`, LaTeX will employ an em-dash as the connector between the page numbers. That's highly unusual, to put it mildly. Do consider changing the field to `pages={713--719}`.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of condensing your code into an MWE. Feel free to revert.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

> But the standard way to make [a] hyperlink is to create one unified link across the author names and the year, correct? Then I want to follow the standard practice. How can I do that?

I would like to begin by echoing the view that @moewe has expressed in a comment, that there may not be a single, let alone "standard", way to create a hyperlink from an author-year style citation call-out to the corresponding formatted bibliographic entry. AFAICT, having the citation call-out feature two separerate hyperlinks or a single, unified hyperlink is equally good. For sure, I can't see readers ever getting confused by the fact that a citation call-out may contain two separate hyperlinks.

A solution to your question is actually readily available in [Audrey B.'s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27235/5001), posted in 2011, to the query [natbib and hyperref for (Author, Year) style produces two links](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24136/5001). Happily, even though the code is more than 11 years old by now, it would appear to continue to work just fine. This could be due to the fact that the `natbib` package hasn't experienced any major changes either over this time period.

Consider the following example and associated screenshot. The citation call-outs produced by `\citet{Coase1992AER}` and `\citep{Coase1992AER}` are now single hyperlinks. And, in the citation callout "(Coase, 1992a,b, 1993)", the particles `Coase, 1992a`, `b`, and `1993` are 3 separate hyperlinks, not 4. Aside: observe that the parentheses that surround the output of `\citep` are *not* part of the hyperlink. This practice is "standard" for the `natbib` citation management package.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,english]{extarticle}

%% Create a bib file on the fly:
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{Reference.bib}
@article{Coase1992AER,
  title  ={The Institutional Structure of Production},
  author ={Ronald H. Coase},
  journal={American Economic Review},
  volume ={82},
  number ={4},
  pages  ={713-719},
  year   ={1992},
}
@misc{Coase1992alt, title={Thoughts}, author={Ronald H. Coase}, year=1992}
@misc{Coase1993, title={Further Thoughts}, author={Ronald H. Coase}, year=1993}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[sort,round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % or some other suitable bibliography style

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}

%% The following code block is copied straight from Audrey B.'s answer
%% given at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27235/5001

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter

\pretocmd{\NAT@citex}{%
  \let\NAT@hyper@\NAT@hyper@citex
  \def\NAT@postnote{#2}%
  \setcounter{NAT@total@cites}{0}%
  \setcounter{NAT@count@cites}{0}%
  \forcsvlist{\stepcounter{NAT@total@cites}\@gobble}{#3}}{}{}
\newcounter{NAT@total@cites}
\newcounter{NAT@count@cites}
\def\NAT@postnote{}

% include postnote and \citet closing bracket in hyperlink
\def\NAT@hyper@citex#1{%
  \stepcounter{NAT@count@cites}%
  \hyper@natlinkstart{\@citeb\@extra@b@citeb}#1%
  \ifnumequal{\value{NAT@count@cites}}{\value{NAT@total@cites}}
    {\ifNAT@swa\else\if*\NAT@postnote*\else%
     \NAT@cmt\NAT@postnote\global\def\NAT@postnote{}\fi\fi}{}%
  \ifNAT@swa\else\if\relax\NAT@date\relax
  \else\NAT@@close\global\let\NAT@nm\@empty\fi\fi% avoid compact citations
  \hyper@natlinkend}
\renewcommand\hyper@natlinkbreak[2]{#1}

% avoid extraneous postnotes, closing brackets
\patchcmd{\NAT@citex}
  {\ifNAT@swa\else\if*#2*\else\NAT@cmt#2\fi
   \if\relax\NAT@date\relax\else\NAT@@close\fi\fi}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\NAT@citex}
  {\if\relax\NAT@date\relax\NAT@def@citea\else\NAT@def@citea@close\fi}
  {\if\relax\NAT@date\relax\NAT@def@citea\else\NAT@def@citea@space\fi}{}{}

\makeatother
%% end of copied code block


\begin{document}
\citet{Coase1992AER}, \citep{Coase1992AER}

\citep{Coase1992AER,Coase1993,Coase1992alt}

\bibliography{Reference}
\end{document}
```